# Ajax login redirect

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm using jquery Ajax function to process a user login in a jquery pop up modal. Simplemodal. The script posts the username and password then displays the out come in a hidden div using jquery .show function. The question is in my login script it posts data back fine but how can I redirect the user if there login is successful. Normally I would use a php header but that doesn't reload tr close the modal popup just loads the header into the popup.

Can anyone help.

Thanks

Comment: It's JavaScript, so redirect user in one of possible ways. More: http://ntt.cc/2008/01/21/5-ways-to-redirect-url-with-javascript.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Send back your data to the ajax response as an array with a status inside of it.

```
if(logic to determine login was false){
    return json_encode(array('status' => false, 'action' => 'path/to/redirect/to'));
}
```

Then in your response, evaluate the status.

```
success:function(data){
    if(data.status == false){ 
        window.location = data.action;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
document.location.href='/newpage/';
```

Or:

```
window.location = '/newpage/';
```

either one works.

Comment: Thanks but I know how to redirect but needed to redirect Oma. Return condition like above :) thanks